# Как добавить 'Изменить' для файла .SVG в контекстное меню проводника Windows?

Tags: windows

Столкнулся с проблемой:

для .py, .pyw файлов добавить кнопку 'Изменить' у меня получилось,
а вот для .svg файла никак не могу.

все из-за того что приложение по умолчанию для открытия Microsoft Edge.

с файлами html и xml та же шляпа, в реестре данные есть, контекстное меню пунктов нет, но если изменить приложение по умолчанию, то появятся.

Как в файлы Microsoft Edge добавить параметры контекстного меню?

Comment: Как добавляли для .txt, .ini, .py, .pyw?

Comment: regedit.exe \HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\ добавил раздел edit со значением по умолчанию изменить. в ней поддиректория commsnd со значением по умолчанию "C:\Windows\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE"  "%L"

Comment: Причем после установки Inkscape, в реестре появились разделы Inkscape.SVG и Inkscape.SVGZ в которых есть кнопка Open with Inkscape но при нажатии правой кнопкой мыши по файлу такого пункта нет, shift тоже не показывает.

Comment: все из-за того что приложение по умолчанию для открытия Microsoft Edge, но как в него добавить эти кнопки?

Comment: с файлами html и xml та же шляпа, в реестре данные есть, контекстное меню пунктов нет.

Comment: Нужно внести эту уточняющую информацию непосредственно в вопрос через ссылку [edit].